# Проверка на вхождение элемента в список

Tags: excel, vba

Существует список значений *(x, y, z)*. Нужно заполнить ячейку в следующей колонке этими же значениями, если ячейка с первой колонки есть в списке. Если другое значение, то в ячейке нужно записать последнее значение, которое было выше

| in | out |
| --- | --- |
| x | x |
| k | x |
| y | y |
| k | y |
| k | y |
| z | z |
| x | x |
| k | x |

*(x, y, z)* - определено, а *k* - любое значение, которое не равно *(x, y, z)*

Я знаю как заполнить, если есть совпадение, но никак не могу понять, как заполнить значения, что не совпадают

```
Sub test()
Columns(2).Insert
    Dim arr()
    arr = Array("x", "y", "z")
    For i = 10 To 2 Step -1
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(Cells(i, 1), arr, 0)) Then
        Cells(i, 2) = Cells(i, 1)
    Else
        Cells(i, 2) = "Erorr"
    End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Если *нужно записать последнее значение которое было раньше*, то почему цикл снизу-вверх? Просто иди сверху-вниз и в случае ошибки вставляй `Cells(i-1, 2)` (И кстати - если в первой же строке в первой колонке не x-y-z, то что должен сделать алгоритм?)

Comment: @JohnSUN если в первой же строке в первой колонке не x-y-z, то в идеальном варианте ничего не писать, но в целом такой случай в контексте данной задачи невозможен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще и быстрее формулой.

```
=ЕСЛИ(СЧЁТЕСЛИ($D$2:$D$4;A2);A2;B1)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если первое значение не из списка, формула вернет заголовок *out*

Пример работы с циклами

```
Sub FindInList()
    Dim aData(), aList()
    Dim bFlag As Boolean
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    
    aData = Range("A1:B10").Value
    aList = Range("D1:D4").Value
    
    For i = 2 To UBound(aData)
        For n = 2 To UBound(aList)
            If aData(i, 1) = aList(n, 1) Then
                bFlag = True: Exit For
            End If
        Next n
        
        If bFlag = True Then
            aData(i, 2) = aData(i, 1)
            bFlag = False
        Else
            aData(i, 2) = aData(i - 1, 2)
        End If
    Next i
    
    Range("A1:B10").Value = aData
End Sub
```

Comment: спасибо, это решает мою задача, но мне все же интересно как это реализовать с помощью цикла в VBA

Comment: @Julia Kovalchuk, добавил в ответ пример кода